Phase Coherence in the BCS wavefunction and the Cooper Pair Wavefunction
I have a couple question regarding the following BCS wavefunction ($|0\rangle$ is the vacuum state):
$$|\psi\rangle = \Pi_k \big(|u_k|+|v_k|e^{i\varphi}c^\dagger_{k\uparrow} c_{-k\downarrow}\big)|0\rangle $$
The coefficients $u/v$ are the coherence factors and I took this form from Tinkham's book.
First, why exactly can we insert the arbitrary phase in front of $|v_k|$ for every Cooper pair? We can show the BCS theory breaks a $U(1)$ symmetry (down to $Z_2$) due to the pairing term, and we can calculate the standard deviation of the particle number to verify particle number is not conserved. The term which breaks this symmetry involves Cooper pairs, so it seems reasonable to put it there, but I am wondering if there is some more intuition here?
Second, How do we extract the Cooper pair wavefunction from this above expression? It is commonly stated the order parameter of the SC is the Cooper pair wave function and it has the same "breaking" of the $U(1)$ symmetry. Maybe this can make some sort of connection with the above question since we know the order parameter should break the $U(1)$ symmetry, so if I can related the above BCS wavefunction to the Cooper pair wavefunction, I can probably be happy.
Hopefully someone can help! Any sort of discussion of intuition is appreciated since I bet there are MANY ways of looking at this (I have a few more ways I did not include since that would be too many words)

First answer. This is a quantum theory: every amplitude is a priori a complex number.  The most general expression would have all $u_{k}$ and $v_{k}$ complex.  What you do to get that expression here is that you invoke the U(1) symmetry and multiply the state by one overall phase factor
$$
\exp\left[ -\sum_k \arg(u_k) \right]
$$
to cancel out the phase of each and every $u_k$.  Then you have a phase difference left over for $v_k$.
Second answer.  The macroscopic condensate wavefunction of Cooper pair serves as an order parameter.  You can have uncondensed Cooper pairs both in the superconducting and even the normal phases; they are just very strongly damped (happily breaking up into electrons).  In a sense, BCS superconductivity is the BEC of Cooper pairs.
That BCS wavefunction tells you what a Cooper pair at total momentum zero is made out of: you see the amplitude at which the electrons with $\pm \vec{k}$ participate in the paring.  But that counts as "internal structure".  It is the spatial part that tells us if it is a condensate.
So, what about the spatial part?  Well, that BCS ansatz is for a translationally invariant state, and all electron pairs have zero total momentum.  The easy conclusion is that the Cooper pairs condense into the $p = 0$ bosonic single-particle state.  The spatial wavefunction is simply a constant.

I am not satisfied with the second answer, but the first is good. It is intuitive, which is not bad, but we may propose a wavefunction with non-zero COM-momentum Cooper pairs (e.g. a PDW). Now the gap is oscillatory, but the Landau Order parameter is still the Cooper pair wave function. Maybe I'll just expand it again using the usual canonical transformation. Thanks for the first answer!
